# MySQL : select column values which do not repeat with both possible values 1 and -1

Tags: php, mysql

I have dB table as follows

```
id | branch | allot  
 1 | Comp   | -1  
 2 | IT     | -1  
 3 | Comp   | -1   
 1 | Comp   |  1
```

where `allot=-1` means seat is allotted and `allot=1` means seat cancelled

I want a MySQL query which will return id=2,3 only
not id=1 as it has cancelled seat later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question specifically says "later on".  This cannot be done with your data format, because SQL tables represent unordered sets.  And, you have no column that specifies an ordering.

If you want to get `-1` values and exclude those with `1`, there are several ways.  One is to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from dbtable t
where allot = -1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from dbtable t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.allot = 1
                 );
```

If you later discover a column that does have an ordering for the records (such as `createdat`), then you can easily modify this to:

```
select t.*
from dbtable t
where allot = -1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from dbtable t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.allot = 1 and
                        t2.createdat > t.createdat
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`, `branch`, MAX(`allot`)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `id`
WHERE `allot` = -1
```

This way, when 2 rows exist for the same seat, the one where `allot` = 1 is selected (since MAX), then it is finally dropped from selection (since WHERE).

Comment: the id who has allot as -1 (means seat is reserved) but same id has later on allot as 1 (means seat previously reserved is cancelled now) should not be consider now.

Comment: So what? Yes, it's exactly what you get with the query I suggested. More precisely, from the example in your initial post, you'll get only `id`s 2 and 3.